# Output enable logic of AM26LS32AID

Tags: circuit-analysis, pcb-design, schematics

I am planning to use [AM26LS32AID](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/am26ls32a.pdf?ts=1632373294174&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) in my design. In order to enable the output pins of this chip, G and #G need to be connected to VCC and GND respectively as per the datasheet.

AS per the below logic diagram, G and #G uses OR gate.

Can I connect the G to GND and #G to GND, as at this input the out of OR gate is Logic 1 and can the out be enabled?

[image]

Comment: According to that schematic, it ought to work.

Answer (score 0):

Crucial for understanding the role of these two inputs are two rows of table **Pin Functions**, section **5 Pin Configuration and Functions**, page 3/32 of the datasheet:

\${\overline {\text {G}}}\$   `12   15   I   Active-Low select`

\$\text {G}\$    `4    5   I   Active-High select`

You fix one of the inputs `G (G')` to the constant logic level according to your needs and use the other input `G' (G)` to dynamically select A/B lines, either with active-low or active-high signals according to your choice of a constant-connected input.

Answer (score 0):

There is a table in the datasheet that explicitly indicates the various states for the enables. (see table 1 on page 11).

Both enables at ground (low) do make the output active.

[image]

Comment: Both \$\text {G}\$ and \$\overline {\text {G}}\$ inputs can make the output active, but input \$\text {G}\$ activates the output when the value of \$\text {G}\$ is at **high**, and input \$\overline {\text {G}}\$ activates the output when the value of \$\overline {\text {G}}\$ is at **low**. Notice that the **low** logical value is not necessarily **ground** (although it can be ground), as well as the **high** is not necessarily \$V_{CC}\$ (although it can be \$V_{CC}\$).